# Graphic design courses under a Creative Commons license?

Tags: education, open-source

I'm an amateur graphic designer, with a decent head for theory, and intermediate skills. I would like to run a graphic design course for my friends, but I would prefer not to spend months on developing the course. I recently ran a workshop on using git, and for that I used [someone else's open source git tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/mrezny/gittutorial), which I modified, and expanded. I would love to be able to do the same with a graphic design course (ideally, a short series of workshops).

Is anyone aware of such a course? e.g. a set of editable slides, or a course outline/framework, that is available under an open source license (creative commons, GFDL, etc.)?

There are plenty of courses available on youtube, but for the most part, they aren't available under an open license, so I can't re-use the content. There is also the [wikibooks graphic design book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Graphic_Design), but it's pretty empty, and also not really in a suitable format.

Comment: I'd love to know the reasons for the downvotes. I'm happy to modify the question, if people can suggest improvements.

Comment: No idea, seems like a good question to me. All I can guess is maybe people thought you meant courses on open source design software (e.g. Inkscape, Gimp) not courses that are themselves open source/creative commons, so got the wrong idea from the title, or (hopefully not) they're doing that thing of assuming that everyone hasn't researched their questions before asking. Maybe you could add a line like "The closest I can find is... but that doesn't work because..."?

Comment: re. the question itself: it's worth being aware that [**Creative Commons**](http://creativecommons.org/) is bigger in the design world than open source (what with it being about media more than code),  and can be used for [open educational resources](http://creativecommons.org/tag/open-educational-resources), so if you've been searching on "open source" and finding nothing, you could try creative commons instead.

Comment: I like this question. I've not heard of such a resource but if there is I'd be interested in checking it out!

Comment: @Yisela: Probably would make sense to start fleshing out the wikiversity courses first, and then create a set of slides from that, as necessary. If I do, I'll post it on bitbucket or github, and link to it from here.

Comment: @naught101 Makes more sense, indeed :) I'll take a look, see if there's something I can help with!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of courses [related to graphic design on Wikiversity](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Graphic_Design). Most of these are only partly written, and not yet useful, or only tangentially related to graphic design, but it is a wiki, so I guess they could be expanded.